# Is there a Java 8 utility for simple list mapping?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to do a very simple map across a `List<T>` to extract a single value of type `R` via a lambda, and return a new `List<R>`

Or for a more concrete example, if I have a `List<Person> people` and I want to convert it into a `List<String>` via `Person::getName`:

I can do this with code like:

```
people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even make my own utility function:

```
public static <T,R> List<R> simpleMap(List<T> source, Function<T, R> accessor) {
    return source.stream().map(accessor).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
simpleMap(people, Person::getName)
```

But I was wondering if I'd missed a standard Java 8 utility to do this?

Comment: What is the criterium to "to extract a single value"?

Comment: In my actual code, I'm calling a getter like "getName()" that returns a String property.  I'll update my example to make that more obvious.

Comment: I don't think there's some utility to do this. Your util method looks nice and I would stick to it.

Comment: If every intermediate method of the Stream pipeline had a "simple" version as you suggest, that would explode the API. You'd have simpleFilterToList and simpleFilterToSet (since why should the output be always a list?) and simpleMapToList and simpleMapToSet and so on. Not so simple anymore. `list.stream().map(Thing::getField).collect(Collectors.toList());` is simple enough and doesn't require simplification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the usual idiom: get a stream from the list, apply the mapping function and collect the result.

You can reduce it with a static import to

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
...

List<String> peopleName = list.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(toList());
```

AFAIK there is no utility method, as the stream approach is rather short to write and defining such methods would result in an API explosion.

Also it's may worth looking at the Guava API which already defined [a transform method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.transform;
...

List<String> peopleName = transform(people, Person::getName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with one method on stream. It doesn't look much simpler thought.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;


List<String> peopleName = list.stream().collect(mapping(Person::getName, toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing simpler than stream-map-collect in Java 8. The designers didn't want to mix intermediate and terminal operations in the collections API.